# pyephem to iterate through dates

Tags: date, pyephem

```
m = ephem.Moon()
m.compute('2007/01/11')
j = ephem.Date('2007/01/11')
for add in range(1, 10):
    print (ephem.date(j + add)), m.dec[j]
```

This errors out, but I was looking for suggestions.

Is there a way to iterate through dates using `Pyephem`? I am trying to run a for loop that changes dates as it runs.

Comment: in the future it would be useful if you post the exact error you are getting

Comment: Thanks Water I'll do that in the future!

Comment: Feel free to upvote / select my answer if you found it helpful, otherwise let me know in a comment if you are still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'ephem.Angle' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

There does not seem to be an issue with how you are iterating through dates. The m.dec object does not support indexing.

If you remove `, m.dec[j]` from the end of your last line, the code runs without error and prints the following:

```
2007/1/12 00:00:00
2007/1/13 00:00:00
2007/1/14 00:00:00
2007/1/15 00:00:00
2007/1/16 00:00:00
2007/1/17 00:00:00
2007/1/18 00:00:00
2007/1/19 00:00:00
2007/1/20 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Mr. Water! Sorry for being unclear, but I wanted to iterate through dates to find where the planets were over time, so that is the functionality that I needed. I know that you can't call m.dec[], but that is how I would like it in theory.

Additionally, is there a way to call planet Earth in pyephem?